# Spritekit - Collision & Contact Issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, collision

I have an object at the bottom of my screen that can be tilted by tilting the device. It can be hit by falling objects that fall randomly and when that happens it will show "Game Over!". However, if it hits on of the walls (as seen in code below) it will show the "Game Over!" message as well. How can I fix this? I want it to be able to hit the wall with nothing happening. (I'll add the current code for the contact delegate as well).

**Code For Walls:**

```
//Left Wall
SKNode *node = [SKNode node];
node.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, CGRectGetHeight(self.frame))];
[self addChild:node];


// Right wall
node = [SKNode node];
node.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:CGRectMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.frame) - 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame))];
[self addChild:node];
```

**Code for Contact Delegate:**

```
#pragma mark contact delegate
- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {
    //Create two physics body objects
    SKPhysicsBody *firstBody, *secondBody;
    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask) {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA;
        secondBody = contact.bodyB;
    }
    else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB;
        secondBody = contact.bodyA;
    }

    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & dodgerCategory) != 0) {
       [secondBody.node removeFromParent];
       self.takenHits++;
    }if (self.takenHits >= 1) {
       //Game Over
       UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Game Over."
       message:@"You have been hit!" delegate:self
       cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
       [alert show];
       self.paused = YES;
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the wall's `contactTestBitMask` to zero in order for it not to be tested for contact with other objects (or set the required bit(s) to be tested with specific objects if you need to)

```
node.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = 0;
```

Set it for both walls nodes.

In order for the balls to collide with the walls set their collisionBitMask to the propery category bits:

```
ballNode.categoryBitMask = <Ball category bit>
ballNode.collisionBitMask = <wall category bit>

leftWallNode.categoryBitMask = <wall category bit>
leftWallNode.collisionBitMask = <ball category bit>

rightWallNode.categoryBitMask = <wall category bit>
rightWallNode.collisionBitMask = <ball category bit>
```

In short the `categoryBitMask` defines "To which category do I belong" in the physics world and the `collisionBitMask` defines "With which categories I can collide with in the physics world"

If you have problem defining the bits let me know (use 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08 etc...)

Comment: I don't have anything for the balls colliding with the walls actually... but the balls don't make a difference if they touch the wall as it won't affect the game... should it be fine or should I add any extra code?

Comment: do the balls bounce back from the walls or they just going through them ?

Comment: @giorashhc The balls fall directly down from the top of the screen and disappear when they hit the ground and resting, it hardly touches the wall. Also, as a side note, when I add that code, it doesn't make a difference, I just need it to be able to bounce off the walls without affecting anything else.

Comment: See my edit regarding setting the category and collision bit masks

Comment: What difference do the numbers at the end make when defining the bits?

Comment: use a different one for each different category (i.e. ball = 0x01, wall = 0x02) in these numbers only one bit is set at a different location in the binary representation thus making it possible to do a simple logic AND operation to decide if two objects collide. Take a look here : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52519/discussion-between-user3578149-and-giorashc)